# Get search completion terms from wiki using curl

Tags: curl, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using the wikipedia rest api to find completions for a search term.

Their rest api as document [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=opensearch), shows the example,

```
Find pages beginning with Te.
    api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te
```

In curl command, i am using,

```
curl -H "accept:application/json" -X GET 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te'
```

It returns empty result, whereas i can see, this api gives a [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te) as,

```
["Te",["Te","Texas A&M University","Texas State Highway 52","Texas Farm to Market Road 60","Tern","TES4","Texas Tech University","Teetotalism","Temple Knights","TED (conference)"],["This is a redirect
```

Is any of the curl parameters wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl does not automatically follow redirects. Use `curl -v` to diagnose problems.

```
$ curl -vH "accept:application/json" -X GET 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te'
(...)
< HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect
(...)
< Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te
(...)
```

Comment: Just use HTTPS in the first place.